# How to dynamically evaluate the mathematical formulas for each field in WEB API 2

Tags: .net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am looking for a best solution in web API on how to evaluate the mathematical formulas and set the result/output in the property field.

Lets say I have the following entity with two properties. Likewise I could have many properties with different formulas.

```
public class DomainEntites
{

    public float centimetertometer{ get; set; }
    public float inchtofeet { get; set; }

}
```

I have the formulas like below saved in my database.

```
     key              formula
     ----             -------
     c_m              a * 1000
```

My idea is to pass the key and execute the formula whereever it is applicable. something like this so that I can reduce the complexity of code and make it generic.

```
public class DomainEntites
{
    [UnitConversion(key="c_m")]
    public float centimetertometer{ get; set; }
    [UnitConversion(key="inch_feet")]
    public float inchtofeet { get; set; }

}
```

Idea is **UnitConversion** class or may be custom attribute, not sure, will the read the value and key and accordingly converts to as per the formula in the database.

My dilema is I am not able to implement this in WEB API. I was trying with custom attribute but no luck so far.

Let me know if anybody need more information. I am using Angularjs in front end.

Any advise on the solution is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best approach would be to create entity with many different units like

```
public class Length
{
    public float Centimeters{ get; set; }
    public float Inches { get; set; }
}
```

Do not involve source unit with fields names. It's just bed practice. You just want result in different units - source unit doesn't matter.

Your main problem by looking at your model is that you have trouble with separating your Data and What You Want To Do With It.

Then you can solve the conversion in 2 ways.

First you can create one WebApi action method for conversion which will take as input value and unit and use some backing helper class to do the conversion and return the result. (read about startegy/template method and factory patterns).

Second is creating service class per each (size/value) you want to convert and inside that class you create method for every unit conversion. (this approach requires much more code and is less generic).